# Android: get RGB color (instead of ARGB) from resources

Tags: android, colors, android-resources

If I write:

```
getResources().getString(R.color.colorname)
```

I will get the color in ARGB string format (eg. "#ffccaa33")

How can I get the color in RGB string format instead (eg. "#ccaa33") ?

Answer (score 3):

You can simply ignore the last two characters of the returned String (the last two characters are usually the characters for the alpha).

If it is a custom color that you have defined in a resource file, `getResources().getString(R.color.colorname)` will return the exact value of the color as you have defined it. So, if you have defined a color with 6 characters (no alpha) it will give you what you want.

EDIT: what I mean by String processing is:

```
String colorValue = "#" + getResources().getString(R.color.colorname).substring(3,9);
```

Comment: I am verifying something different:
1) the alpha value is the first 2 characters
2) no matter how you specify the color, `getResources().getString(R.color.colorname)` will always return you #aarrggbb

Comment: oh... well, you can still do String processing, i will edit my answer